# Java - "for-loop" - incompatible types

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

```
void testK(ArrayList list) {
        for (int y= list.size() ; y > 0 ; y-- ) {
            Kostka kst = list.get(y -1); 
        }}
```

when I try to compile this code, it says that the `(y -1)` (3rd line) is incompatible

- but the `list.size()` method should return an integer, so whats the problem ?

Comment: please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Of what type is your `ArrayList` ? 
It Should be `ArrayList<Kostka> list`

Comment: @Doorknob he is saying compiler error

Comment: okay, then please post the full error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using a [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) for the `ArrayList` passed in, therefore you need to cast

```
Kostka kst = (Kostka) list.get(y -1);
```

but better to use generics to avoid casting

```
ArrayList<Kostka> list
```

Answer (score 7):

You either have to cast the result of `list.get()` to your type

```
Kostka kst = (Kostka)list.get(y -1);
```

or work with generics and supply a generic list to your method

```
void testK(ArrayList<Kostka> list)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the way you have written your code, the `get(y - 1)` will return an `Object` instance.

You have to cast it:

```
Kostka kst = (Kostka) list.get(y -1);
```

Also, avoid using raw types like `ArrayList`. Instead, use Generic collections (`ArrayList<Kostka>`)

Answer (score 1):

First I suggest you to use generics for `ArrayList`.

like

```
   void testK(ArrayList<Kostka> list) {
    for (int y= list.size() ; y > 0 ; y-- ) {
        Kostka kst = list.get(y -1); 
    }}
```

or you need to cast the object got from list to your type `Kostka`

```
void testK(ArrayList list) {
        for (int y= list.size() ; y > 0 ; y-- ) {
            Kostka kst = (Kostka)list.get(y -1); 
        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tip for enhancement : put the `-1`a the beginning of the loop, so you avoid `list.size()` substractions in the *loop*. If possible, keep `Koska ksk` *final*.

```
for (int y = list.size() - 1; y > 0; y--) {
    final Kostka kst = list.get(y);
}
```